# Why it's so hard to move large number of files (say your own user profile in windows 10) to another drive

Tags: windows-10

[image]

Often explorer stuck at this screen for a very long time and after that stupid screen disappear, the file is still isn't moved.

Any software that can move or sync files more easily?

I finally manage to did it by moving small amount of files a little at a time which is very annoying and time consuming. Took a few days to be honest.

Comment: It might have been easier to copy rather than move the files. Software recommendations are off-topic here, but maybe the [User State Migration Tool (USMT)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/usmt/usmt-overview) from Microsoft would have worked.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you moving these folders / files?

Some of the folders and files in Appdata\Local are unique to the computer you are using, highly secured, and not readily movable. That is why it is taking so long.

What is the point in moving files unique to the computer?

You can back up a User Profile to an external drive, but to use the document and email files in that profile, you would have to take Ownership to the files.

You can back up a User Profile in Advanced System Settings, but that will not let you use unique settings from the old computer on the new computer.

So then make a new User Profile on the new computer and copy over the documents you need. Copy documents, export favorites and import on new machine, close Outlook, copy PST/OST files over (Outlook keeps Outlook settings in the cloud). Make notes for setting up other apps.

Best to backup the documents, data and email you have and not "Everything"

Comment: Because I want to move the setting to another computer

Comment: And why the the hell it is taking so long just because it's not readily moveable. I copy first and then move by the way

Comment: That will be very difficult to do. Settings for your existing User Profile are unique to your existing computer.  The settings on the new machine will be different in some way than on the old machine.

Comment: Make a new User Profile on the new computer and move the documents you can move.

Comment: You can use Advanced Systems Settings to backup a User Profile.  But that does not move settings.

Comment: I want things like my google chrome profiles. There are like 20 of them and I don't want to set those up again on another computer. Most have cookies and some sites already I can open without login.

Then there's metamasks wallet

Comment: Some Apps keep settings in their cloud setup.  Otherwise, so far as I know, you cannot just copy the user profile over. As you have seen, that does not work. I have stopped using Tabs and Favorites. New Search finds my pages in seconds. Easier.

Comment: Don't forget that you can export browser favorites and import on the new computer. I do that. Other settings in other Apps can be exported and imported on the new computer.  There are numerous ways to bring over settings.  "Documents" is a very broad term.